# How to find a basis for the kernel and image of a linear transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $$A=
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & 6 & -18 \\
>         0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \\
>         0 & 0 & -2 & 6 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Find a basis for the kernel and image of the linear transformation $T$ defined by $T(x) =Ax$.

---

My question is how do you handle the first 2 columns of A which are all zero's?  Does that mean the top 2 values of the basis of the kernel are variables? both zero?  The methods I know for calculating the basis for the kernel and image of a transformation matrix are not producing the correct answers in WebWork.

Answer (score 0):

By elimination, you will end up with 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives you the dimension of the image of $T$ and the kernel of $T$.

Now, you can read from the matrix a basis for the image of $T$. On the other hand
$$
-x_3+3x_4=0
$$
tells you how to find a basis for the kernel of $T$.

Comment: Explicitly, the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ do not show up in the equation defining the kernel tells you that $[1 \, 0\, 0\, 0]^T$ and $[0\, 1\, 0\, 0]^T$ are in the kernel. Take these together with a vector of the form $[0\, 0\, x_3\, x_4]^T$ that satisfies the equation, and you've got your basis.

Answer (score 0):

Image is spanned on linearly independent columns of matrix $A$, which follows from definition of matrix of linear transformation. To find it do the row reduction of $A^T$ and its nonzero columns span the image, or equivalently, if you row reduce $A$ then columns with pivots will correspond to columns of $A$ that form image of the transformation.
Kernel is set of vectors $x$ such that $Ax=0$. To find it's base you need to solve system of equations given by $Ax=0$.

Answer (score -2):

The kernel basis is:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0&0&1&1/3\\
    \end{array}
\right]^T, \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right]^T, \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0&1&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right]^T$$

The image basis is:

$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      6&-1&-2\\
    \end{array}
\right]^T$$